# the question about showing that Every affine variety is variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

A question I want to ask is...

> **Question**. Show that every affine variety $X$ (in $\mathbb{A}^n$) is a variety

I want to elicit the above result by using the given theorem.

> **Thm**. $X$ is variety if and only if $\triangle X$ is closed in $X \times X$. (Where  $\triangle X$ is a diagonal set, i.e $\triangle  X= \left \{(x,x) | x \in X \right \}$)

In order to show that $\triangle X$ is closed in $X \times X$, my idea is to find out "the zero set of $S=?$" Because "zero set of $S$" is closed form of the Zariski topology. Anyway, my claim is

**Claim** : $\triangle X = Z(?)$

First, consider the coordinate $(p_1,....p_n; p_1,....p_n):=(p;p)$   and then let $I(X)=(f_1,...f_n)$ be a ideal in $X$ where $f_i \in \bar{k}[x_1,...,x_n]$. Then every  $(p;p)  \in \triangle X$ , $(f_i \circ \pi_1)(p;p)=0 $ for all $i=1,2,....n$ (where $\pi_1 : X \times Y \to X$ ) From there, I find the answer.  $S:=\left \{ f_i  \pi_1 : f_i \in I(X)=(f_1,....f_n) \right \}$.   $\triangle X = Z(S) \subset X \times X $.

Though, I do not believe my proof is right following two reasons : $1)$ there is  a flaw/are flaws during the proof. (In this case, is my thought right? $2)$ This proof does not be used the condition "$X$ is affine variety"(or equivalently, $X $ is irreducible algebraic subset). In other words, this proof does not depend on whether or not $X$ is affine variety.

**Edit** *(About the uncertainty of the question)* : I referred the discussion uploaded youTube (However, the language is not English..) The sequence of the lecture is going like this :

> **Prop1.** Let $X,Y$  be affine varieites. Then $X \times Y$ satisfies universal property : For any affine $Z$and a morphsim $F:Z \to X, G: Y \to X$, there is a unique (rational morphism) $\Phi : Z \to X \times Y $ such that $F= \pi_{X} \circ \Phi, G=\pi_{Y} \circ \Phi $

> **Proof**. (Omit in this question)
>
> **Thm** $X$ is variety if and only if $\triangle X$ is closed in $X \times >X$. (Where  $\triangle X$ is a diagonal set, i.e $\triangle  X=
> > \left \{(x,x) | x \in X \right \}$)
>
> **Proof**. (Omit in this question)
>
> **Cor**. Every affine variety is a variety.

Comment: It would help tremendously if you added some information about what your setup for varieties is. For instance, are you working with subsets of $k^n$, schemes, what? Second, there is no issue with not using the fact that $X$ is irreducible here - any locally closed subset of a space with $\Delta$ closed in the product will also have it's diagonal closed in the product.

Comment: I do not surely catch the meaning "working with .....", However, at least, my question  is not related to the "schemes " and seems to be related to "working subsets of $k^{n}$" (because "scheme" is not yet mentioned while I am reading material...)

Comment: Look, you need to add enough of your definitions so that people reading your question can tell what's going on, because it's not clear right now. Are you working out of a particular text? If so, that would be something to include. Please make an [edit] including this information.

Comment: None of the information you've added addresses the issue of *what your definition of an affine variety is*. There are many possible (but equivalent in some sense) definitions, and in order for you to get good help, you need to specify what yours is.

Comment: I follow this definition : A set $X \subset \mathbb{A}^{n}$ is an affine variety if "$X$ is irreducible algebraic set".(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_variety#Overview_and_definitions)